# Understanding array declaration in C

Tags: c, arrays, declaration

I'm trying to understand how the C Standard explains that the declaration can cause an error. Consider the following pretty simple code:

```
int main()
{
    char test[1024 * 1024 * 1024];
    test[0] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4460c4ad2487fc8)

This segfaluts. But the following code does not:

```
int main()
{
    char test[1024 * 1024 * 1024];
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29e398f25b88ef47)

But when I compiled it on my machine the latest one segfaulted too. The main function looks as

```
00000000000008c6 <main>:                        
 8c6:   55                      push   %rbp                            
 8c7:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp                                         
 8ca:   48 81 ec 20 00 00 40    sub    $0x40000020,%rsp        
 8d1:   89 bd ec ff ff bf       mov    %edi,-0x40000014(%rbp) // <---HERE    
 8d7:   48 89 b5 e0 ff ff bf    mov    %rsi,-0x40000020(%rbp)                      
 8de:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
 8e5:   00 00                       
 8e7:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
 8eb:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 8ed:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax       
 8f2:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
 8f6:   64 48 33 14 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rdx
 8fd:   00 00                              
 8ff:   74 05                   je     906 <main+0x40>
 901:   e8 1a fe ff ff          callq  720 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 906:   c9                      leaveq
 907:   c3                      retq
 908:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 90f:   00
```

As far as I understood the segfault occurred when trying to `mov    %edi,-0x40000014(%rbp)`.

I tried to find the exaplanation in the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), `Section 6.7.9 Initialization`, but it does not seem to be the relevant one.

So how does the Standard explains this behavior?

Comment: Different levels of optimization? Try compiling with `-O2`

Comment: @KeineLust I didn't specify any optimization flags when compiling on my machine neither in this demos. Just `gcc -c main.c`.

Comment: @KeineLust `O2` makes it work, thanks. But anyway, how about the formal explanation of this behavior? Would be greate to find some reference in the Standard. This is the defined behavior, isn't it?

Comment: yes thats what I say, maybe Coliru is compiling with some level of optimization and skipping the whole program.

Comment: I don't think the standard has anything to do with that. It's implementation defined. Compiler optimizes out unused variables. And it can also optimize stack usage, only allocating stack when needed

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Does the Standard define that the variable with static storage duration are stack allocated? Can compiler allocate them in the heap and just insert `free` function call on function return.

Comment: no the standard doesn't say that auto memory uses the stack. Some compilers could allocate the memory on the heap (and that would work) and free it in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is implementation-dependent

I can think of several reasons of why the behaviour should differ

- compiler seeing that variable isn't used, no possible side-effect, and optimizing it away (even without optimization levels)
- stack resizing on request. Since there are no writes to this variable yet, why resizing the stack now?
- compilers don't have to use the stack for auto memory. Compiler can allocate memory using `malloc`, and free it on exit. Using heap would allow to allocate 1Gb without issues
- stack size set at 1Gb :)

Comment: _and optimizing it away (even without optimization levels)_ good point! no `volatile` no party :P